# SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized in Zipline

Tags: python, zipline, quantopian

i'm install zipline , i follow the website step https://pythonprogramming.net/zipline-local-install-python-programming-for-finance/

when i type import zipline , give me error message , just like

```
>>> import zipline
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\HP T\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zipline\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import finance
  File "C:\Users\HP T\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zipline\finance\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import execution, trading
  File "C:\Users\HP T\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zipline\finance\trading.py", line 23, in <module>
    from zipline.assets import AssetDBWriter, AssetFinder
  File "C:\Users\HP T\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zipline\assets\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .assets import (
  File "C:\Users\HP T\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zipline\assets\assets.py", line 604
    self.engine.execute(self._select_most_recent_symbols_chunk(sid_group),
    ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

thanks for you help  ,
John

Comment: It looks like an incompatibility error with Python 3.

Comment: The page you link to says that zipline only supports Python up to 3.5; which interpreter version are you using? (It also describes Windows support as "hacky"; given the choice, that sounds like something best avoided).

Comment: i fixed it already ! thanks ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed , version only 2.7 and 3.5 , otherwise can't